# Cicular contour map using Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create contour plots of film thicknesses on a wafer using plotly, but would like the outputted plot to be a circle since it is a wafer instead of the default square. Do I have to somehow overlay a circle on to the plot and then exclude anything outside of it after the plot is generated? I prefer using plotly if possible since it looks nice.  I've tried using ggplot as well but for some reason my data doesn't work with it since the x and y coordinates are apparently irregularly spaced.  I've searched around but have not seen any results at least using R.

Thanks!